# Second condition on exclusive or (XOR) in regex

Tags: regex

I would like some help with a second condition on a XOR in this Regex that I'm working on.

This regex aims to get the string that is after the `cn=` and goes until a parenthesis succeeded by an empty space or goes until two closing parenthesis.

In the first case it will be a text after the empty space that I would like to not be on my match data, but I cant get rid of this, for example:

`(&(cn=Another (test)))
(&(cn=Another (test)) (objectClass=group))`

In this example above I would like to get only **Another (test)**

I tried a negative lookahead but cound't make it work.

What I got so far:

https://rubular.com/r/DVV830IGSGiNSf

Edit:

What I need to get is the string that is inside the same parenthesis as the `cn=` text is, except for the `cn=` itself. I need what is highlited:

(&(cn=**Testing**))

(&(cn=**Testing**) (objectClass=group))

(&(CN=**Te(st)ing**))

(&(CN=**Te(st)ing**) (objectClass=group))

(&(cn=**Another (test)**))

(&(cn=**Another (test)**) (objectClass=group))

(&(cn=**Access RW \Srv-corp\ScriptsDesenv**))

(&(cn=**Access RW \Srv-corp\ScriptsDesenv**) (objectClass=group))

(&(cn=**Acess( )**))

(&(cn=**Acess( )**) (objectClass=group))

Comment: What you ask for is `cn=\K[^)]*\)(?=[ )])` but this matches more than you want against given input string in rubular. So please refine your requirements.

Comment: @revo Edited, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately Ruby 2.* supports recursions which your requirements depend on. Use the following regex:

```
(?i)cn=\K(\(\g<1>\)|[^()]*)+
```

See [live demo here](https://rubular.com/r/5dnZDhBlCugAxU)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?i)` Enable case-insensitive match
- `cn=` Match `cn=`
- `\K` Reset output
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `\(\g<1>\)` Recursive match where an opening parenthesis is seen
  - `|` Or
  - `[^()]*` Match anything other than `(` and `)`
- `)+` End of CP #1, repeat as much as possible

Comment: Really really appreciate your solution, but unfortunately I'm using ruby 1.9.3 (yeah, I know) :(

Comment: Then you could use this `(?i)cn=\K(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)+` if you are sure parentheses wouldn't nest.

Comment: This second solution only works on ruby >= 2.0.0 too :(

Comment: Sorry, remove `\K` and use capturing groups: `(?i)cn=((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)+)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the string at the matching parentheses of `cn` and then use `(cn|CN)=([0-9a-zA-Z \\()-])+`